# How I fix the profile image not being displayed on start up screen?

Tags: macos, startup

Every time macOS starts I am presented with a startup screen that doesn't display the profile image. How does one fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you set an image at the settings > users and groups?

I'm posting this as an answer to add my example:

[image: users and groups]

When I'm logged out, I see this image properly at MacOS.
You could try replacing the image with another image to test it.